# how to connect spark client/job to access ignite server running in kubernetes with pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, ignite

I am new to spark and ignite and using spark 3.2 with Ignite Ext 3.0.0 and running ignite in kubernetes cluster but not able to connect the spark app with ignite. can someone please provide  some example or documentation to connect spark client/job to ignite server running in kubernetes?

not able to connect the spark app with ignite

Comment: Hi, have you checked examples from ignite-extensions repo?
https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions/tree/master/modules/spark-ext/examples
I don't know anything about spark also, but from my expirience ignite examples are good starting point

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking for pyspark examples